# How can I change page text from the backend in Velo by Wix

Tags: javascript, velo

How could I change text on the page from the backend using Velo by Wix? Is this possible? I want to do this since I want to display confidential information about the current user, and I don't want to give the frontend access to a function that would return that info so I could do it from the frontend.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wix uses .jsw files to handle front-end calls to the backend.
The functions are called by the client but performed by the server

As a very basic example, let's say you want to get a wix-secret from the backend, and display in a text element

page.js:

```
import {getSecret} from 'backend/test.jsw'

$w.onReady(async () => $w("#secretText").text = await getSecret())
```

backend/test.jsw:

```
import wixSecretsBackend from 'wix-secrets-backend';

export function getSecret() {
    wixSecretsBackend.getSecret("secretName")
}
```